# Oracle Apex - Dynamic Actions

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

In Oracle Apex- Dynamic Actions:

My Queries about in Dynamic action to enable/disable two different items as below.
I am working with apex 5 and need to do enable/disable with these item

Having two items in my apex page

1. `p1_text_field`
2. `p2_select_list`

I want to disable the `p2` when I am entering value in `p1` which is enabled to type
vise-versa
I want to disable the `p1` when I am entering value in `p2` which is enabled to select the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For item `p1_text_field`:

1. Create a dynamic action with properties: `Event` - `Key down` or `Change`, `Selection Type` - `Item`, `Item(s)` - `p1_text_field`
2. Add a `Client Side Condition`: `Type` - `Item is null`, `Item` - `p1_text_field`. This condition will allow you to unlock disabled field in a case you clear `p1_text_field`
3. Add `True action` with type `Enable`, `Selection Type` - `Item`, `Item(s)` - `p2_select_list`
4. Add `False action` with type `Disable`, `Selection Type` - `Item`, `Item(s)` - `p2_select_list`

After that, when a user input something into `p1_text_field`, `p2_select_list` will be disabled. If the user clears value of `p1_text_field`, `p2_select_list` will be enabled. If you don't need this, do not create `Client Side Condition`.

Repeat same steps for `p2_select_list`.

**UPD - Important notice**

I forgot about one "feature" of APEX. When you create a new true or false action, check field `Fire on initialization`. It have to be `No`, otherwise action will be executed on page load. The main problem is that APEX sometimes creates new actions with this field set to `Yes`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is a Client-side condition - `Item is null` for this case.

Comment: @Abinnaya I forgot about one thing, check the answer.

Comment: i have done as you suggested but both the field are disabled now :-(

Comment: What is version of your APEX - 5.0 or 5.1? They have a little different properites of actions. I tried my solution in 5.0 - it works.

Comment: Mine is 5.1 , now for select list its working but for text field the same logic is not working, ex :if i am entering some text then the select list item is not disabling.

Comment: It depends on event type. If you use `KeyDown`, it works immediately, if you use `Change` - it works only when the item loses focus.